# How to pass more than one hidden parameter from jsp to servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

I want to pass more than one hidden parameter from **jsp** to **servlet**.
when I code like this. It throws error

```
Here is the code and exception

<% ProductCategoryDAO categoryDAO=new ProductCategoryDAO();
    ProductCategory category=null;
    if(request.getParameter("catogoryId")!=null){
    category=categoryDAO.findById(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("catogoryId")));
    }
     %>
     <form action="AdminController" method="POST" name="frmaddProductCategory"  >
        **<input type="hidden" name="categoryAction" value="editProductCategory">**
        <h1 align="center">Product Category Details</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Product Category</legend>
            <ul>
            <li>**<input type="hidden" name="categoryId" id="categoryId"  readonly="readonly"
                    value="<%=category.getProductCategoryId() %>"/>**
                </li>
                <li><label for="categoryCode">Category Code</label> <input
                    type="text" name="categoryCode" id="categoryCode" required="required" maxlength="12" readonly="readonly"
                    value="<%=category.getProductCategoryCode() %>"/>
                </li>
                <li><label for="categoryName">Category Name</label> <input type="text"
                    name="categoryName" id="categoryName" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100" 
                    value="<%=category.getProductCategoryName() %>"/>
                </li>
                <li><label for="description">Description</label> <input
                    type="text" name="description" id="description" maxlength="500" value="<%=category.getDescription() %>"/>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Category">
    </form>
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.editProductCategory_jsp._jspService(editProductCategory_jsp.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
    at bnms.controllers.admin.AdminController.doGet(AdminController.java:346)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jun 22, 2013 3:40:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```

Comment: it is hard to understand the problem with out providing much information. it will be good if you can post complete exception log and your form markup a little bit more

Comment: Ankit, there is not any different method to access hidden parameters in servlet than normal parameters. I have explained this in your previous question. JasperException is caused due to some other problem. You need to post all code and stracktrace

Comment: thanks friends for your help. here i have posted brief code and exception. I am not able to diagnosis the problem, that how to send more than one hidden parameter from jsp to servelt.

Comment: Hidden parameters will be set when browser sends request to server. It will not be set when page translation happens at server and response is being sent to the browser.  If a single jsp is handling both phases then chances are you are trying to access some object too soon prematurely.  Looks like your category object is null when you access its properties in jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% ProductCategoryDAO categoryDAO=new ProductCategoryDAO();
    ProductCategory category=null;
    if(request.getParameter("catogoryId")!=null){
    category=categoryDAO.findById(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("catogoryId")));
    }
     %>
```

Please check your 'category' object after this part. I think it remain as null. Please don't minkle with this error and hidden parameter. this error happened because of try to accessing null object.

Comment: You can provide comment to do this, You don't need to write this thing as answer

Comment: Sorry Im new here. I cant see link to add comment for question.

Comment: @Pikrut . You are absolutly right. I was doing that silly mistake. Now my problem is solved. thanks friends. :)

Comment: @pikrut My mistake, I think it needs 15 reputations points to be able to add comments